# 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' not registered when using SqlConnection

Tags: c#, .net, sqlconnection

I'm stuck in following situation:

I am using using `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` to communicate with my database.

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(_settings.Database_SqlConnectionString))
{
    con.Open();

    var qryDateChanged = "...;";
    DateTime dateChanged;

    if (DateTime.TryParse(new SqlCommand(qryDateChanged, con).ExecuteScalar().ToString(), out dateChanged))
    {
        if (lastWriteTime > dateChanged)
        {
            var stUpdate = "...";
            new SqlCommand(stUpdate, con).ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

My connection string is built like this:

```
public String Database_SqlConnectionString
{
    get 
    {
        var conString = 
                $"Data Source={Database_Server};" +
                $"Initial Catalog={Database_Database};" +
                $"User Id={Database_User};" +
                $"Password={Database_Password};";
        //var conString = $"" +
        //    $"Server={Database_Server};" +
        //    $"Database={Database_Database};" +
        //    $"User ID={Database_User};" +
        //    $"Password={Database_Password};";
        return conString; 
    }
}
```

And works as intended:

```
[INFO] 15.12.2020 11:23:13 >> "Using Connection String: Data Source=[redacted];Initial Catalog=[redacted];User Id=[redacted];Password=[redacted];"
```

But somehow when using the posted `SqlConnection` initialization, I get the error

> The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'-Provider ist not registered on the local computer.

Now, couple of things to note:

- My local SQL Server is 2017 Express - and here this code works (who would've thought)
- On the target SQL Server 2012 SP4, the exception shown above is thrown

Does anyone have some important information on this topic? Maybe something I am missing, or has encountered a similar problem?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

As mentioned in the comments and the one answer, this is an Access error. My exception wasn't thrown when initializing the `SqlConnection`, but rather when using some stuff from LinqToExcel. I unfortunately misinterpreted that.

The answer regarding the "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable" seems to be the solution.

Comment: No way. That's an Access error. Somehow, somewhere, you're trying to use an OleDbConnection instead of SqlConnection. At the very least post the actual *full* exception text

Comment: To put it another way, if what you claim is true, hundreds of thousands of developers would have noticed, 8 years ago

Comment: What is the connection string?  ACE is  a driver that comes with Microsoft Office and you must have the same version of Office installed (or runtime dll) for version 12.0 which is Office 2007.  See following for connections string to be used with SQL Server : https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: I completely agree and somehow It dawned right now. I am using LinqToExcel...... A 100% my error is thrown there and I misinterpreted something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the similar problem and I've resolved it by installing Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable on the server. But my app working with the excel workbooks.

[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)